# how to make sub-menus under menus in a side-Navigation?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am having the following array in my ts file:

```
public pages: Page[] = [
    { name: 'Smart ', link: '/smart', icon: 'crop_landscape', id: 'markRectangle'},
    { name: 'Shop', link: '/options', icon: 'crop_landscape', id: 'markRectangle'},

  ];
```

I am rendering this array in the side navigation using *ngFor:

```
<mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let page of pages" [routerLink]='[page.link]'>
          <button mat-icon-button id="{{page.id}}"  (click)="rightNavOpen(true,page?.name)">
          <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">{{page?.icon}}</mat-icon>
          <span id="shapeName" [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'">{{ page?.name }} </span></button>
        </a>          


        </mat-nav-list>
```

My requirement is that under the Shop Tab I Want to show the show some more submenus.Is that possible if I add something under the array Pages.

Comment: Check https://stackblitz.com/angular/lnxdekxooyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnested-menu-example.ts

Comment: Where are the sub menus in your pages?

Comment: @Rohit.007 i have not implemented them currently but i want to display them  under the shop tab in the sidenavigation itself.

Comment: Then here is the complete direction https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-sidenav-menu

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your html code little. earlier you were looping over anchor() so we cannot create child in it because it will make all the element inside clickable with the same link then added a child loop inside it.

```
public pages: Page[] = [
{
  name: 'Smart ',
  link: '/smart',
  icon: 'crop_landscape',
  id: 'markRectangle',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'Show More',
      link: '/smart',
      icon: 'crop_landscape',
      id: 'markRectangle',
      children: [

      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: 'Shop',
  link: '/options',
  icon: 'crop_landscape',
  id: 'markRectangle'
},
```

];

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let page of pages" >
     <a matLine [routerLink]='[page.link]'>{{ link }}</a>
     <button mat-icon-button id="{{page.id}}"  (click)="rightNavOpen(true,page?.name)">
      <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">{{page?.icon}}</mat-icon>
      <span id="shapeName" [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'">{{ page?.name }} </span>
     </button>

     <mat-list-item *ngFor="let child of page.children" >
        <a matLine [routerLink]='[child.link]'>{{ link }}</a>
        <button mat-icon-button id="{{child.id}}"  (click)="rightNavOpen(true,child?.name)">
         <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">{{child?.icon}}</mat-icon>
         <span id="shapeName" [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'">{{ child?.name }} </span>
        </button>
     </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: This still needs a fair amount of Angular understanding if OP is going to convert this into a viable solution. Can you make your answer more specific to their question?

Comment: saw it I am checking it.But just for my interest is there any possible way that if i add anything to the array "Pages" like children or something.WIll it help?@kurt any suggestions?

Comment: yes it will help but now depends on you menu depth. If it is nth level then you have to create recursive child menu selector which will render it till the last level

Comment: @Rohit.007,this is  not working.I am getting the  buttons on side nav but upon clicking nothing is happening including the routing.ANy other help.